# Core Plot X axes image in device not showing correctly

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am implementing core plot in ios app. i am using images in X axes. To implement images in X axes  i am using following code

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_16.png"];
    CPTImage *background = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CPTBorderedLayer *imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
    imageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:background];
    CPTAxisLabel *iconLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:imageLayer];
    iconLabel.offset = 8;
    iconLabel.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location+0.5);        
    
    if (iconLabel) {
        [xLabels2 addObject:iconLabel];
        [xLocations2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
```

and set "x3.axisLabels=xLabels2;"

When running these code in simulator it working fine and images shown below
[image]
but when running in real device it looks like below
[image]

image not showing fully in real device...

Comment: try to pass the image scale, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504354/1702413

Comment: Thanks TonyMKenu... But CPTImage *fillimage = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:bubble.CGImage scale:bubble.scale]; is not working in iOS 7